# What is "у меня" in "после русского языка у меня будет химия" why not " после русского языка я буду в лекцию химия"?

Tags: грамматика

There is a typical construction that I do not know specially when concerning about movements, in which we use the preposition y instead of the subject?

Comment: Do you really mean русския as the second word?

Comment: There is no movement in your example.

Comment: Sorry kcd o wrongly wrote i Will edit that thank you

Comment: "после русского языка я буду в лекцию химия" - this is totally wrong and ungrammatical, two errors in prepositions and two wrong cases. "I will into a lecture chemistry"

Comment: Are you sure. Because the is not a construction of mine, I just saw it in my material and I really trust it, but if you explain I would pay attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Russian prepositions can express either motion/tramsition, or state (both evidential and non-evidential).

The stumbling block is usually how to distinguish between a motion (or transition) and a state.

As prepositions, both ***на*** and ***в*** can be used to express either 'a  translative/motional or 'an existential' state.

The difference is expressed by a case ending (and a case).

Locative (AKA 'Prepositional') is normally used with 'existential' state, while Accusative suggests motion or transition. Cf:

***Я на химии*** (existential, Feminine Locative, non-evidential).

***Я на химию*** (motion, Feminine Accusative, non-evidential).

Suppose there is a room called 'химия' between pals of a chemistry lab. A guy willing to express his literal acts or states would use phrases like:

***Я в "химию"*** (motion, Feminine Accusative, evidential)

***Я в "химии"*** (existential, Feminine Locative, evidential)

In Russian, a possessive structure (e.g. phrases like 'I have', 'I own', etc.)  is always a structure of state. Hence, it is possible to say

***После русского языка я (буду) на лекции / на химии***

***После русского языка у меня будет химия***

***После русского языка я - на химию***

but not * ***После русского языка я буду в лекцию химия.***

Answer (score 6):

The phrase *у меня есть* means possession = *я имею* (I have). Your sentence contains this phrase in the future tense *у меня будет* (I will have, I am having). The sentence should be:

> После русского языка у меня будет химия (лекция по химии).

You can use another verb to describe your action.

> После (урока) русского языка я пойду на лекцию по химии.

("Я буду на лекции" is understandable too, but sounds a bit clumsy.)

Comment: "я буду на лекции" only seems valid in a context like "с двух то трех я буду на лекции, не звони мне в это время", or something like that

Answer (score 4):

The following article explains your subject rather well:

http://masterrussian.com/aa120199a.shtml

Your example, in particular, has a direct English analogy: *I have Chemistry after Russian* sounds quite regular.