# Why do not use prepositional case to indicate position in the following sentence

Tags: грамматика

The phrase is: "Часто днём бегу в спортзал или в бассейн".

If the author wants to emphasize on the action rather than where he does the action, he uses the places in nominative? I would expect from what I learned something similar to
Я часто бегу в спортзале или в бассейне.

Comment: It is clearer with a feminine noun: они живут в Москве = they live in Moscow, он хочет ехать в Москву = he wants to go to Moscow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To describe **location** where the action is performed, i.e. to answer the question **Где? (Where?)**, you need a construction "`в/на` + noun in **prepositional** case".

> Я бегаю в спортзале.
>   Он плавает в бассейне.
>   Я гуляю на улице.
>   Птица сидит на дереве.
>
> *I run at the gym. He swims at the swimming pool. I walk in the street. A bird sits on the tree.*

And if you want to describe **direction** of an action, i.e. to answer the question **Куда? (Where to?)**, you need a construction "`в/на` + noun in **accusative** case".

> Я иду в спортзал.
>   Он бежит в бассейн.
>   Я выхожу на улицу.
>   Кошка лезет на дерево.
>
> *I am going to the gym. He is running to the swimming pool. I go out into the street. A cat is climbing the tree.*

Your example belongs to the second type (direction), that's why the nouns are in accusative (which is equal to nominative for these exact words).

Answer (score 1):

The phrase ***Часто днём бегу в спортзал или в бассейн*** means a transition (translative) state emphasising the direction whereto a speaker is headed.

The phrase ***Часто днём бегу (better: бегаю) в спортзале или в бассейне*** means the location where the action of running is taking place.

The issue itself deals with three non-explicit categories of [translativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illative_case), [existential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_clause) state and [evidentiality/non-evidentiality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidentiality), which I have  explained in a response to [your other question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14070/what-is-%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-in-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%8F-why-not-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83).